# Is there a way to prevent the VB6 compiler from shuffling the contents of files?

Tags: vb6

For reasons unknown, the VB6 compiler often likes to reorder the contents of .vbp files and the control descriptor block at the top of .frm files (The code that describes the properties of controls on the form.  Code that you don't see in the IDE but you do see in a text editor and *when doing diffs against the previous revision in version control*.).  This is monumentally annoying and very distracting when comparing revisions of a file.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: this reminds me of a hideous compile time problem we had with a large VB6 app... basically someone reordered the members in a custom user control .ctl file and the compiled started to barf with some totally unrelated message. It worked when we rolled back in VSS so we just put it back how it was!

Comment: I've done that before on forms when I needed to insert new tabs into an existing SSTab control in-between two other tabs, which was easier than adding the new tabs to the end and then manually cutting/pasting between tabs to get everything right. As long as you're careful, you can make it work ;-)

Comment: Replaced `annoyances` tag with `annoyance`.

Comment: Partial duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511302/how-to-deal-with-vb6-vbp-file-references-changing/16844710#16844710. We developed a hook script for for version control that re-ordered the .vbp file before committing. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16844710/1073262 Wasn't brave enough to tackle the .frm files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there's much you can do about this. I've noticed the same problem: the IDE likes to rearrange things for seemingly no apparent reason. Some things I've noticed:

- When you use the SSTab control, VB
  likes to rearrange properties for
  tabs, especially the TabEnabled
  property.
- For project files, it randomly
      rearranges the order in which files
      appear and I think I remember seeing
      cases where similar file types are
      not always grouped together and end
      up mixed in with the project
      properties. You don't have
      much control over this, unless you run all your VBP's through some type of sanitizer that groups like files together (forms in one group, modules in another group, etc.) and sorts them alphabetically or something, so that they remain consistent. One possible way to handle this could be to write an IDE add-on that automatically does this everytime you save changes to a project file, or come up with some batch process that will just recurse over your source directories and clean up all the VBP's in one go.
- The IDE seems to randomly change the
      case of things; this seems to happen
      frequently to project references.
      Sometimes they are output in lower
      case, and other times they are
      output in upper case. You can get
      around this by choosing "Ignore
      Case" when you diff files in
      SourceSafe.
- Control coordinates, such
  Top, Left, Height, and Width, can differ between
  two revisions of the same form. This is due
  to different developers using
  different screen resolutions and/or
  different screen DPI settings while working on the same form.
  If you aren't doing this already, I
  highly recommend that you get
  everyone to develop using the same
  resolution and same DPI setting.
  The differing values are caused by rounding errors that
  occur when logical screen
  coordinates at different resolutions/DPI settings
  are converted to twips, the default
  coordinate space that VB uses for
  laying out forms. Additionally, while I'm on the topic, make
  sure everyone has their display set to 96dpi,
  because if you develop VB forms at
  120dpi, there is a really really good
  chance they won't display correctly
  on a display set to 96dpi.
- There are probably other things I
      can't remember right now...

As for the order of controls being changed in form files, this is normal, and you usually don't want to try rearrange the order of controls by hand if it happens to change from one revision of the form to the next. The order that the controls appear in a form file determines their Z-order on the form. If the order of the controls changes in the .frm file, this will change their relative Z-order on the form, which could lead to unintended results in how your forms are displayed.

Comment: The form control order is directly determined by the Z order. Reordering the project file can also be done by closing, reopening and saving the project. It prefers documents and resource files to be at the end. of the files with build options.

Answer (score 1):

Can you make the .vbp file read-only when you aren't editing it (ie, adding modules, etc)?

As far as form files...I can't think of any good way at all to make VB not reorder them.  But I have to say that I've never encountered this before.  Are you sure that something else isn't going on?

It's entirely possible that I just never paid any attention to this in the past, so I'm not saying you are mistaken, just offering my own observations.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that re-opening the form and saving again often restores a consistent order.