# How can I prevent random numeric code changes in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb6

I am currently working with a legacy Visual Basic 6 application. On occasion, when I make changes to a .frm file, and then save, other seemingly random numeric changes will also be saved.

Some examples of these random changes are

- Font Size changes (8.25 to 7.8)
- Screen Positions
- Control Sizes

After interrogating the version history, it appears this was not always a problem. It only started happening in 2013.

Why are these numeric values changing? and how can I prevent it from happening in the future?

Comment: They are tailored for your screen resolution/dpi

Comment: @alex Thanks for your reply, can you suggest how they can be prevented?

Comment: It should only change when run on a machine that has a different screen setup that the one that last saved the .frm - See the last bullet @ http://stackoverflow.com/a/169716/246342

Comment: All developers touching the UI source modules have to agree on using the same small fonts or large fonts OS setting. (VB6 does not work with custom font sizes).

Comment: @alex, would you like to make your comment an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are tailored for your screen resolution/dpi; the values in the .frm file should only change when run on a machine that has a different screen setup than the machine on which the file was last saved.

Answer (score 1):

Use 'Format -> Lock Controls' menu option and if you use the same machine/screen it should not change.

Comment: Thanks KMan, but we have multiple developers working on the same code base.